# Ethereum minimal library for Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ethereum, smartcontracts

I need to be able to call Ethereum contracts (read only eth_call will do) and store the result in my Google Sheet. Any reasonable way to do this using a Google Apps Script? I couldn't find any way to import libraries like web3 or ethrpc...

Comment: I used an entry point with ethrpc on Cloud

Comment: Did you try pasting the entire library in an Apps Script project, and sharing it as a library? So it can be used by other scripts?
Have a [look at this workaround](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2012/11/using-open-source-libraries-in-apps.html) to add open-source libraries to Apps Script Projects.

You might have to do some kind of wrapper too.

Comment: @Aerials I tried that with some libraries but always got errors. Some of these libraries use transport functions which are not available in Google Apps (it only supports UrlFetchApp.fetch) and others seem to use various Javascript structures which I guess are not supported either. I even tried to add just the much simpler ethereumjs-abi library and even that one fails with some errors which don't seem easy to fix...

Comment: @contributorpw will be hard to call a contract without at least a basic ABI library...

Comment: Did you try using the eval() function?

[Load External JavaScript Libraries in Google Scripts with eval()](https://www.labnol.org/code/20380-load-external-javascript-with-eval)

Comment: @Aerials that's the first thing I did. Returning an error for all these libraries. I don't think it's different than including the source. They are simply not compatible with the Google variant which is more strict than general Javascript.

Comment: I found a library that could help that seem to compile without errors: https://github.com/ethjs/ethjs-abi/
But when I run it through eval it just returns true. Any idea how to actually store the result function into that abi object so I can use the functions defined there?

Comment: Have you tried [deploying your Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) project as a web app?
You could load any of your required libraries on the HTML using `<script>` tags.
Then you could use AJAX to call the Ethereum contracts, and with the response run your web app's `doPost(e)` function.
This gives you the possibility to use the [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class to put the data in a spreadsheet.